# Why NVL() doesn't work in the following outer join(+)?

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join, nvl

I'm trying to outer join the two tables, and when there is a null value displayed in the column of "Full Name", replace it with 'No one'.

The outer join worked fine, **the problem is,  the null value is still    null, not 'No one'.**

The following is my code.

```
SELECT 
NVL(to_char(e.FIRST_NAME||' '||e.LAST_NAME),'No One') "Full Name",
d.DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES e,DEPARTMENTS d
WHERE e.DEPARTMENT_ID(+)=d.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

Follwing is a screenshot of the result. 
[image]

Thanks for having a look!

Comment: I would use [coalesce](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm) instead of `NVL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"NVL does not work" because there will always be at least a space character in the argument to NVL.

```
SELECT 
decode(e.FIRST_NAME||e.LAST_NAME,null,'No one',e.FIRST_NAME||' '||e.LAST_NAME) "Full Name",
d.DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES e,DEPARTMENTS d
WHERE e.DEPARTMENT_ID(+)=d.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

could be a working alternative.

Comment: That is the problem! Thanks! But how should I fix that when I still want to keep the space between the first name and last name? @user2672165

Comment: @Wilheim added a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike other databases, Oracle allows the concatenation of `NULL` values in strings.

I would write your query as:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN e.FIRST_NAME IS NULL AND e.LAST_NAME IS NULL THEN 'No One'
             WHEN e.FIRST_NAME IS NULL THEN e.LAST_NAME
             WHEN e.LAST_NAME IS NULL THEN e.FIRST_NAME
             ELSE e.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || e.LAST_NAME
        END) "Full Name", d.DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM DEPARTMENTS d LEFT JOIN
     EMPLOYEES e
     ON e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

Notes:

- This uses proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  The `(+)` notation for joins is ancient and deprecated.  You should learn proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- The logic no longer has extra spaces at the beginning/end of a name, when one of the values is missing.
- The logic is explicit and uses the ANSI standard `CASE` expression.

And to add, there are fancy ways of shortening the expression:

```
coalesce(trim(e.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || e.LAST_NAME), 'No One')
```

I just think the `case` logic is much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Because the expression `e.FIRST_NAME||' '||e.LAST_NAME` is never null. In case the row is outer joined, the value is `' '`.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one mentioned it yet, you can use NVL2 which has the form:

```
NVL2(<expression>, <value if expression is not null>, <value if expression is null>)
```

So you could simply do:

```
NVL2(e.FIRST_NAME||e.LAST_NAME, TRIM(e.FIRST_NAME||' '||e.LAST_NAME), 'No One') "Full Name"
```

The TRIM is case it's possible that either the first or last name can be null (but not both); it would remove the trailing/leading space that would be left over.